# Make for PythonMagick results in infinite loop

Tags: macos, makefile, pythonmagick

I'm trying to get PythonMagick installed on my Macbook running MacOS 10.9.4.

I've followed a set of instructions from various pages, including a very helpful page found here: http://www.geero.net/2011/03/install_pythonmagick_mac_os_x/

However, whenever I run `make` (or `sudo make`), it seems it ends up in a loop, repeating the following set of lines continuously:

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config -I/opt/local/include -        I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I -I/opt/local/include -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6 -g -O2 -DBOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -MT libpymagick_la-_CompositeOperator.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpymagick_la-_CompositeOperator.Tpo -c _CompositeOperator.cpp -o libpymagick_la-_CompositeOperator.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/libpymagick_la-_CompositeOperator.Tpo .deps/libpymagick_la-_CompositeOperator.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config   -

I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I -I/opt/local/include -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6  -g -O2 -DBOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -MT libpymagick_la-_GravityType.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpymagick_la-_GravityType.Tpo -c -o libpymagick_la-_GravityType.lo `test -f '_GravityType.cpp' || echo './'`_GravityType.cpp
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../config -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I -I/opt/local/include -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6 -g -O2 -DBOOST_PYTHON_DYNAMIC_LIB -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -MT libpymagick_la-_GravityType.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libpymagick_la-_GravityType.Tpo -c _GravityType.cpp  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/libpymagick_la-_GravityType.o
In file included from _GravityType.cpp:7:
In file included from /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++/Include.h:42:
In file included from /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h:71:
/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/method-attribute.h:120:11: warning: 'magick_alloc_size' macro redefined
#  define magick_alloc_size(x)  __attribute__((__alloc_size__(x)))
          ^
/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/method-attribute.h:132:11: note: previous definition is here
#  define magick_alloc_size(x)  /* nothing */
          ^
In file included from _GravityType.cpp:7:
In file included from /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/Magick++/Include.h:42:
In file included from /opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/MagickWand.h:71:
/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/wand/method-attribute.h:121:11: warning: 'magick_alloc_sizes' macro redefined
#  define magick_alloc_sizes(x,y)  __attribute__((__alloc_size__(x,y)))
          ^
/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6/magick/method-attribute.h:133:11: note: previous definition is here
#  define magick_alloc_sizes(x,y)  /* nothing */
          ^
2 warnings generated.
```

The `configure` command I use is:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7" LDFLAGS=-L/opt/local/lib
```

Can anyone see why this is failing or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that happening for the same file (or files) over an over again or is that just happening for all the various files that are being compiled (but each one only once)?

Comment: It is happening for the same files, so the lines in the block are repeated verbatim over and over again...